# Change Bash filename autocompletion for aliases to be different than default

Tags: bash, autocomplete, tab-completion, bash-completion

I have a custom alias for `vim` that I use for opening TeX files (allows proper functioning with [`vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex):

```
alias vtex="vim --servername VIM"
```

It would be great if tab-completion of files only accepted `.tex` files — for example, if I'm in a directory with only one `.tex` file but many others, typing

```
vtex [TAB]
```

would automatically complete to

```
vtex file.tex
```

rather than all the other files `vim` is generally capable of editing.

I tried to use `complete` as follows

```
complete -f -X '!*.tex' vtex
```

but this didn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: How does it not work? The only downside I can see is that it also completes with directories ending in `.tex`.

Comment: It just doesn't work. Autocompletion suggests all files, not just those ending in .tex.

Comment: That's not what I see. It filters the current directory and only suggests files ending in `.tex`. How and where do you set `complete`?

Comment: Do you have the alias defined? It works fine as long as you don't have an alias; there's something about the phrase being aliased that doesn't make it work on my end.

Comment: Hmm, no, I just set the completion. Let me tree with the alias set.

Comment: No, same, still works for me.

Comment: You're 100% right. My mistake was not adding the complete line in my .bashrc - I thought it persisted across terminal sessions. I don't know if there's a more canonical place to put complete commands, but .bashrc seems to work fine. Thank you for your help!